# Automated Craft 3 installation

Tags: installation

I am setting up a vagrant development environment and I was wondering if it is possible to somehow pass the installation configuration when running `./craft setup` command to avoid any user interaction?

Checking the help output of the `setup/index` says --interactive: boolean, 0 or 1 (whether to run the command interactively.). When executing `./craft setup --interactive 0` nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong? I tried searching for an explanation and usages of `setup` parameters but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line syntax for install without user input should be:

`./craft install --interactive=0`

There's a great article describing just such an automated approach [here](https://medium.com/@timknight/moving-from-mamp-to-valet-for-craft-cms-3-and-everything-else-587cfee5cf4c).